# Value of pointer different from what it is assigned to

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two empty functions called TestFunc and TestFunc2, and I assigned their addresses to two variables.

```
void TestFunc()
{
}

__declspec(naked) void TestFunc2()
{
}

int main()
{
DWORD* test = (DWORD*)TestFunc;
DWORD* test2 = (DWORD*)TestFunc2;

printf("TestFunc is %p at test is %p\n", TestFunc, test);
printf("TestFunc2 is %p at test2 is %p\n", TestFunc2, test2);
getchar();
}
```

After assignment, the value of the two variables actually differ from what they are assigned.

However, in a printf statement, the output shows that they are the same. Any ideas why is this happening?

[image: Picture]

Comment: What is `TestFunc` and `TestFunc2`? Functions? Member functions? Variables? Something else? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: My bad, indeed they arent. I meant to use DWORD* instead. But my question still stands, the values of the variables differ from what they are assigned. I mentioned in my post that, TestFunc and TestFunc2 are functions.

Comment: @eXPerience is it debug or release bulid? At what point of execution do you look in the watch?

Comment: @eXPerience Please post a [MCVE] that reproduces the behavior yo claim. Also note that function pointers may have a different size than `DWORD*` pointers.

Comment: It's in debug build. I've inspected the watch tabs immediately after assignment and print statements. The values in the watch tab remained the same throughout execution.

Comment: `TestFunc is 01101190 at test is 01101190
TestFunc2 is 01101118 at test2 is 01101118`, this is the output I'm getting. I think the output is fine.

Comment: @Muhammad Ahmad Yes, the output from the printf statements show that they are the same, however, as you can see from the watch tab in my picture, they aren't. I'd like to know why this is happening.

Comment: @eXPerience can you try and make your variables global and volatile?

Comment: @Amomum http://puu.sh/rxrry/a6c5187345.png . There you go, variables still differ. Printf statements still output the same addresses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by [incremental linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf%28VS.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Visual Studio, from this page you can learn that one of the drawbacks of this is:

> An incrementally linked program is functionally equivalent to a program that is non-incrementally linked. However, because it is prepared for subsequent incremental links, an incrementally linked executable, static library, or dynamic-link library file:
>
> - Is larger than a non-incrementally linked program because of padding of code and data. Padding enables the linker to increase the size of functions and data without recreating the file.
> - May contain jump thunks to handle relocation of functions to new addresses.

and those ***jump thunks*** is what your have observed.

if you disable this option (vs2015):

Linker -> All Options -> Enable Incremental Linking to NO

then your addresses will be equal.

If you look closer in disassembly what is at the address which you have assigned to DWORD*, you will find that there is a jump to your function:

```
TestFunc:
000000014001117C  jmp         TestFunc (01400116D0h)
```

Comment: This was it! Thanks for the explanation. However, there was no JMPs at the assignments. http://puu.sh/rxrVA/8f4cef6f57.png

Comment: You need to lookup value in your DWORD pointer variable, and check what code is at that location.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the platform specific runtime environment your code is compiled to. C++ allows the runtime to do some pointer arithmetics behind the scene. It is dangerous to write any code that relies on this runtime behaviour.

If you really want to know, take a look at the assembler code at the memory. My guess would be that the runtime uses an extra jump table perhaps for the new edit and continue debug functionality that is improved/changed with each release of visual studio.